# Custom Policy-Based Authorization in asp.net

Tags: configuration, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on custom policy based authorization in asp.net web application

I followed the steps given in the below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies

I have created authorization requirement and Authorization Handlers 
for registering handlers in the service collection the `ConfigureService` method has to be added in `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Over21",
                          policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new MinimumAgeRequirement(21)));
    });
    services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, MinimumAgeHandler>();
}
```

But, when I debug the code  this `ConfigureService` method is not invoked.
Do I need to add any reference?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Authorization services before adding MVC services.

Comment: Thanks for the reply            http://scottdorman.github.io/2016/03/17/integrating-asp.net-core-dependency-injection-in-mvc-4/   I have followed the above link to solve this issue now the configure service method is getting called but when calling the method for which the policy is applied the authorization is not happening